# How to get the new order of the columns in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

The column headers are not bound in my application.

It is specified like this

```
<DataGrid Name="grid1" AutoGenerateColumns="False"     CanUserReorderColumns="True" AllowDrop="True">
 <DataGrid.Columns>
       <DataGridTextColumn Header="Column1" Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}"/>.. so on.
```

After the user changes the order of the columns through drag and drop, how do i get the new order in the code behind? I have not followed MVVM pattern.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [AutoGeneratingColumn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.autogeneratingcolumn(v=vs.95).aspx) event for changing/setting order of columns.

[How to: Customize Auto-Generated Columns in the DataGrid Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc903950(v=vs.95).aspx)

[DataGridColumn.DisplayIndex](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.displayindex(v=vs.110).aspx) --Gets or sets the display position of the column relative to the other columns in the DataGrid.

Comment: Ah!! It doesn't work for hidden columns though. When I hide the columns, the displayIndex property doesn't return the right values.